# How to get subprocess to display command that is being excuted on machine

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I can use the following functions to execute commands on the machine BUT I don't get to see the bash prompt or the command that was issued.

```
def test12():
    global cmd_list, cmd_string
    sub_proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_list, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()

def test13():
    global cmd_list, cmd_string
    sub_proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_string, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

Is there a way to route/view what command was executed and what the shell prompt is?
I already have it sending back to the main script everything that gets displayed after the command executes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get the shell prompt itself with either of these techniques. In the first case, no shell is run. Its either fork and exec for unix systems or ExecuteProcess for Windows. In the second case, the shell is called to execute one single command. On linux, for example, the command is whatever is in the `SHELL` environment variable. On my system it ran `/bin/sh -c testprogram`, which ran the program without going through the shell prompt.

If you want to see the command, print it before you run the program.